# How can I change individual object's attributes in the Raphael SET?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Let's consider I have a `circle` and a `rectangle` in **`ss`** `Raphael Set`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500),
        r     = paper.rect(100, 100, 140, 80),
        c     = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);

    c.attr({fill: 'red', stroke: 'black'});
    r.attr({fill: 'black', stroke: 'red'});

    var ss = paper.set(r, c); 

</script>
```

Now at some point in the program, I need to change say Circle's **`fill: 'white'`**.

I know that it is possible to change Set's attribute as follows: `ss.attr({fill: 'white'}),` but this applies to all of its elements. I still want to keep the color of rectangle unchanged. I have tried **`ss.c.attr()`**, but no result.

***Any idea how can I achieve this. Thanks***

Comment: Why not just `c.attr({fill: 'white'})`? Is there a reason you can't directly access `c`?

Comment: Because I need to get already created ss set and do some changes with it from some event handler. c is not visible to me, I only have the set.

Comment: I found that I can use set.forEach(), but not sure how to achieve use it.

Comment: How come `c` isn't visible to you?

Comment: Well, if someone gave you an array of Rarhael sets, how you know what those sets consist of? There should be a way to get the objects from a Raphael set right? So that later by knowing what type of object we are dealing with, we can change its attributes ;)

Comment: c is invisible: but if i get it from the set, i can apply attribute function on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. Then I found out that you can access `SET` individual objects just like in array. 
For exp.; **`ss[0]`** returns your **r** rectangle object; i.e. ss[0].attr({'//here'})